# Induction to sum of binomial coefficients

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

Here's the problem. Prove by induction:
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n-p} {n\choose k} \cdot {n\choose p+k} = \frac{(2n)!}{(n-p)!\cdot(n+p)!} $$
My approach is to use the following formula: $ {n+1\choose k} = {n\choose k} + {n\choose k-1} $. We get:
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n+1-p} {n+1\choose k} \cdot {n+1\choose p+k} = \sum_{k=0}^{n+1-p} \left[ 
{n\choose k} \cdot {n\choose p+k} + {n\choose k}\cdot{n\choose p+k-1} + {n\choose k-1}\cdot{n\choose p+k} + {n\choose k-1}\cdot{n\choose p+k-1} \right] = \left[ \frac{(2n)!}{(n-p)!\cdot(n+p)!} + {n\choose n+1-p}\cdot{n\choose n+1} \right] + ... $$
So I got gibberish. Maybe I have to prove for $ n+p $?

Comment: Notice that the RHS is $\displaystyle\binom{2n}{n-p}$.

Comment: This isn't gibberish. With sufficient patience your approach should work. Note that $\binom{n}{n+1}=0$, so you already have one simplification. Your induction hypothesis should be stated clearly. I believe it best to take the hypothesis to be that the identity holds for a fixed $n$ and arbitrary non-negative integers $p$. You will need to use the formula you used on the left side on the right as well, probably multiple times.

Comment: If you aren't wedded to an inductive proof, you could try a combinatorial proof instead.

Comment: @WillOrrick , yeah there are some simplifications along the way. But I have no idea what to do with the part $ {n\choose k-1} \cdot {n\choose p+k} $.

Comment: Try changing the summation index. Let $k'=k-1$ and rewrite as a sum over $k'$ from $-1$ to $n-p$ (but you can drop the $k'=-1$ term since $\binom{n}{-1}=0$). Now you have a sum just like the one in the induction hypothesis, except that $p$ is replaced with $p+1$.

Answer (score 1):

By [Vandermonde's Identity](https://bit.ly/3xFSBLN) you have;

$\binom{m+n}{r}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{r}\binom{n}{k}\binom{m}{r-k}$

now replace $r=n-p$ and $m=n$